# Tips on building a program detecting pupil in images

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I am working on a project that aims to build a program which automatically gives a relatively accurate detection of pupil region in eye pictures. I am currently using simplecv in Python, given that Python is easier to experiment with. Since I just started, the eye pictures I am working with are fairly standardized. However, the size of iris and pupil as well as the color of iris can vary. And the position of the eye can shift a little among pictures. Here's a picture from wikipedia that is similar to the pictures I am using:
["MyStrangeIris.JPG"](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MyStrangeIris.JPG) by Epicstessie is licensed under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en)

I have tried simple thresholding. Since different eyes have different iris colors, a fixed thresholding would not work on all pictures.

In addition, I tried simplecv's build-in sobel and canny edge detection, it's not working especially for eyes with darker iris. I also doubt that sobel or canny alone can solve the problem, given sometimes there are noises on the edge of the pupil (e.g., reflection of eyelash)

I have entry-level knowledge about image processing and machine learning. Right now, I am thinking about three possibilities:

1. Do a regression on the threshold value base on some variables
2. Make a specific mask only for edge detection for the pupil
3. classification on each pixel (this looks like lots of work to build the training set)

Am I on the right track? I would like to reach out to anyone with more experience on this type of problem. Any tips/suggestions are more than welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I'm relatively new to the site. I was wondering why my questions is voted-down? Just want to know, so I can improve when I post next time.

Comment: It is probably because the question is too broad and doesn't have a specific solution. Regardless, I think it is a detailed question though!

Comment: @Flying_Banana Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about iris classification, but I've done written digit recognition from photos. I would recommend tuning up the contrast and saturation, then use a k-nearest neighbour algorithm to classify your images. Depending on your training set, you can get as high as 90% accuracy.

I think you are on the right track. Do image preprocessing to make classification easier, then train an algorithm of your choice. You would want to treat each image as one input vector though, instead of classifying each pixel!

Comment: Thank you. Since there're many learning algorithms out there, I have been looking into some but not sure which one will work. I will definitely look into k-nearest neighbour.

Comment: Be careful that a lot of machine learning algorithms are binary, aka linear classifiers. They can only classify something into two categories. In the case you want more than two, say, you want to classify the ethnicity of the person from the pupil, you want to look for classifiers that can handle multiple categories. knn happened to be the most intuitive and simple algorithm out there that does the job!

Answer (score 2):

I think that for start you should put aside the machine learning. You have so much more to try in "regular" computer vision.

You need to try and describe a model for your problem. A good way to do this is to sit and think how you as a person detect iris. For example, i can think of:

1. It is near the center of image.
2. It is is Brown/green/blue circle, with distinct black center, surrounded by mostly white ellipse.
3. You have a skin color around the white ellipse.
4. It can't be too small or too large (depends on your images..)

After you build your model, try to find better ways to find these features. Hard to point on specific stuff, but you can start from: HSV color space, Correlation, Hough transform, Morphological operations..

Only after you feel you have exhausted all conventional tools, start thinking on features extraction and machine learning..

And BTW, because you are not the first person that try to detect iris, you can look at other projects for ideas.

Comment: Good suggestion. I agree, I will try some more regular computer vision like you have mentioned.

Comment: I have done some research on the topics and read some post on stackoverflow. The ones I found are a bit different from what I'm doing. That's why I decide to post here. But I will definitely continue to look for relevant projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small matlab code for image (link you have provided), function which i have used is hough transform for circle detection, which has also implemented in opencv, so porting will not create problem, i just want to know that i am on write way or not.

my result and code is as follows:

```
        clc
        clear all
        close all

        im = imresize(imread('irisdet.JPG'),0.5);

        gray = rgb2gray(im);

        Rmin = 50; Rmax = 100;
        [centersDark, radiiDark] = imfindcircles(gray,[Rmin Rmax],'ObjectPolarity','dark');

        figure,imshow(im,[])
        viscircles(centersDark, radiiDark,'EdgeColor','b');
```

Input Image:

[image]

Result of Algorithm:

[image]

Thank You

Comment: Hi, thank you! The output looks promising. I am trying to port this to opencv. Since opencv's circular hough transformation is a bit different from matlab's, I am experimenting with it. Then I will try to test this on my sample data. However, I am not sure if this going to work on identifying pupil in iris, since the pupil tends to have lower but not so different intensity from iris in grayscale. I will definitely let you know my results.

Comment: try and post your results. all the best.

Comment: Hi, I first tried the HoughCircles() function in opencv, it's not working because it uses different edge detection method from matlab's. So after experimenting for a bit, I actually tested my sample data on the matlab. After turning up the contrast with certain factor, the matlab's houghcircle function work 99% of time in identifying the iris, and the 1% can be identified by adjusting the factor. So It is great!

Comment: However, neither houghcircle function works on identifying the pupil, because the contrast between the pupil and iris is not so apparent. However, I will probably crop the image an turn-up the contrast somehow maybe using classifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try Active Shape Modelling or if you want a really feature rich modelling and do not care about the time it takes execute the algorithm you can try Active appearance modelling. You might want to look into these papers for better understanding:

[Active Shape Models: Their Training and Application](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjACahUKEwi5i4CtrerIAhVMExoKHfDvDe4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.inf.unideb.hu%2F~sajolevente%2Fpapers%2Faam%2F1995.%2520cviu95%2520-%2520active%2520shape%2520models.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG6HKIqM8og4NWCgBDP7GSpPlpdaw&bvm=bv.106379543,d.d2s)

[Statistical Models of Appearance for Computer Vision - In Depth](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwiqk63nrerIAhVHNhoKHR2yBWw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.face-rec.org%2Falgorithms%2FAAM%2Fapp_models.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFKjoKw38i90Qoh3TKCPZo41OGLEQ&bvm=bv.106379543,d.d2s)

Comment: Thanks! It's very interesting. I will look into it.

Comment: May be you can give me a plus one if it was helpful for you. Desperate times!

Comment: I will, but I am not able to right now... I will give you a plus when I can